# ELSE IF Statement not validating information

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Validate form has been working fine but I have now tried adding email validation to the code and now nothing will validate, form submits without any popup error boxes.

Here's The Current Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
        var a=document.forms["order_form"]["fname"].value;
        var b=document.forms["order_form"]["address"].value;
        var c=document.forms["order_form"]["city"].value;
        var d=document.forms["order_form"]["pcode"].value;
        var e=document.forms["order_form"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=email.indexOf("@").value;
        var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".").value;

        if (a==null || a=="")
            {
            alert("Full name must be filled out");
            return false;
            }
        else if (b==null || b=="")
            {
            alert("Address must be filled out");
            return false;
            } 
        else if (c==null || c=="")
            {
            alert("City must be filled out");
            return false;
            }
        else if (d==null || d=="")
            {
            alert("Post-Code must be filled out");
            return false;
            }
        else if (e==null || e=="")
            {
            alert("Email Address must be filled out");
            return false;
            }
        else if (atpos<1||dotpos<atpos+2||dotpos+2>=email.length)
            {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is `email` definitely a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any declaration for email before following:

```
var atpos=email.indexOf("@").value;
var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".").value;
```

Maybe you meant `e`, not `email`?

Also delete the `.value` after `indexof()` calls, see @charlieftl's answer, we were quite complementary on this ;-)

Comment: I missed this part... `email` is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Form is likely submitting due to the following errors

Change:

```
var atpos=email.indexOf("@").value;
var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".").value;
```

To

```
var atpos=e.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=e.lastIndexOf(".");
```

`indexOf()` returns a number not an object so there is no `value` property.

Also as noticed by @fpierrat `email` should be `e`

Comment: How did I miss the `.value `at the end?! +1

Comment: Thanks for the help!!